# From filename get mountpoint, device, LV, VG, PV names

Tags: shell, filesystems, mount, lvm, block-device

Given a relative pathname, how do I get its:

- Mountpoint
- Device
- LVM LV name
- LVM VG name
- LVM PV name(s)

Answer (score 4):

#### Summary

Given a relative `$pathname`, the following commands will set the following variables:

```
$absolute $mount $dev $lv $vg $pvs
```

**Absolute pathname**

```
absolute=$(readlink -f "$pathname")
```

**[Mountpoint and device](https://serverfault.com/a/369682/322507)**

```
read -r dev mount <<< $(df --portability "$pathname" | awk 'NR==2{print $1 " " $6}')
```

Note: btrfs and zfs filesystems may span multiple devices, but only one will be listed here.

**LV and VG names**

```
read -r lv vg <<< $(sudo lvs -o lv_name,vg_name --noheadings  "$dev")
```

There is no need to worry about possible whitspaces in names as [man lvm(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvm.8.html) says:

> The valid characters for VG and LV names are: `a-z A-Z 0-9 + _ . -`

**PV devices**

```
pvs=$(sudo vgs -o pv_name --noheadings "$vg")
```

There may be more than one PV hosting your VG.

To deal with the edge case of special characters in device names, look into parsing `pvs --reportformat json`.

**Bonus: Loop device backing file**

```
backing=$(losetup -lnO BACK-FILE "$dev")
```

Comment: what about NFS/samba mount ?

Comment: I dont know how portable it is, but an alternative to the `df` is `findmnt  -no source  -T file`

Comment: @Archemar I'm not experienced in those, but point me at anything already existing to be included for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @mueh it's not POSIX and the output isn't exactly clean for btrfs, but it is more informative: `$ findmnt -no source -T ~` gives `/dev/mapper/vg_svelte-home[/@home]`, where `@home` is the subvol that I mounted.

Comment: @mueh I've found that `-v|--nofsroot` will suppress the `[]` addition.